# Adjective meaning "bird-like"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word meaning "bird-like" in the same way that "arachnoid" means "spider-like" or "ichthyoid" means "fish-like"?

An example sentence involving this word would be: "The figure depicted in the cave painting had a [bird-like] appearance to it."

(I looked up the scientific name for birds, "aves", but if I naively try to add an "-oid" suffix I unfortunately arrive at "avoid".)

Comment: By the way, "arachnid" is not just a fancy synonym for "spider";  an arachnid is any of a group of small animals, similar to insects but with four pairs of legs, that include spiders, scorpions, ticks, and mites ([Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/arachnid)).

Answer (score 9):

"Avian" is the usual adjective for bird-like.  "Avine" and "volucrine" (though less common) also work.

Comment: Unfortunately, *avian* is also commonly used as a noun, so its use could cause confusion in some contexts.

Comment: I know that you asked the question, so you must consider this answer at least adequate—but it really isn't very well documented. You could strengthen it by including dictionary definitions (with links to the source reference works) for the words you suggest. Please consider doing so.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I have voted. Thanks for alerting me to this!

Answer (score 7):

Yly's answer of *avian* is probably best. However, *[ornithoid](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ornithoid)* is another, rarer option that ends in *-⁠oid,* like *arachnoid* and *ichthyoid*. Merriam-Webster defines it as follows:

> resembling a bird :  birdlike

*Avis* is the Latin word for "bird" (*aves* is the plural). The adjective ending *-(i)an* is from Latin, and usually comes after a Latin root, although not always. The suffix *-oid* is from Greek, and usually comes after a Greek root. The Greek root for "bird" that is most commonly used in English is *ornitho-.*

A side note: as far as I know, the combining form associated with *avis* is in fact *avi-,* not just *av-.* So I think "avioid" would be preferable to  "avoid" as an adjective derived from *avis* and the suffix *-oid.*
I haven't found any dictionaries that list *avioid,* but I did come across an example online:

> I was wondering, how prevalent are avioids in science fiction,
>   especially in modern science fiction.

– [Kehaar, "rec.arts.sf-lovers" Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.arts.sf-lovers/yHdInI_S-9s)

Comment: Great find. Perfect. +1

Comment: To me, this is a better answer than _avian_ which means _of or relating to birds_ which is different from _bird-like_. +1.